# Need to disable prerasterization so that all fragments (gl_PrimitiveID) are processed

Tags: fragment, particles, vertex, ssbo

I am sending an SSBO array of 112,200 vertices as VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_POINT_LIST linked to the vertices as in Shasha Willems's particle example from his tutorial. I need the vertex shader (gl_VertexIndex) and fragment shader (gl_PrimitiveID) to index all these vertices. But apparently the pre-rasterization is throwing most away and I am only getting 46000.

Is there a way to disable fragment tests so that one fragment is sent to the fragment shader for every vertex?

Tried to disable all depth testing.